# How did this algorithm for computing a^n get rewritten to run in O(log n) time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

Suppose you want to compute a<sup>n</sup>.  A simple algorithm would multiply a, n times, as follows:

```
result = 1;
for(int i =1; i <= n; i++)
    result *= a;
```

The algorithm takes O(n) time. Without loss of generality, assume n=2^k

You can improve the algorithm using the following scheme:

```
 result = a;
 for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
     result = result * result;
```

The algorithm takes O(log n) time. For an arbitrary n, you can revise the algorithm and prove that the complexity is still O(logn)

So confused, so how is n=2<sup>k</sup>, and why is k only shown in the second example? Don't understand how this transformed into a O(logn) time complexity...

Comment: Please, could you state at the beginning what the problem is that the algorithm is trying to solve? And this sounds very much like homework...

Comment: It might help to understand that you are considering a special case, where n is a power of 2. In a special case such as this you can implement the routine more efficiently.

Comment: @nyarlathotep not homework but an example from the textbook,that did not explain why this is so.

Comment: *Without loss of generality, assume n=2^k.* That is a **lot** of loss of generality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second algorithm doesn't work in the general case; it only works if there is some k such that you can write n = 2<sup>k</sup>.  If there is a k where you can do this, then by taking the logs of both sides of the equality you get that log<sub>2</sub> n = k.  Therefore:

- The loop, which counts up to k, runs O(log n) times.
- Therefore, the loop runs in time O(log n).

If you want to get rid of the mysterious k, you could write

```
int result = a;
for (int i = 0; i < log2(n); i++) {
    result = result * result;
}
```

This more clearly runs in O(log n) time, since the loop runs log<sub>2</sub> n times and does O(1) work on each iteration.

I don't think it's fair to say "without loss of generality" that n is a perfect power of two, since not all numbers are!  The above code will only work if n is a power of two.  You can generalize it to non-powers-of-two by using the **[repeated squaring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)**, which has O(log n) complexity but works for any power.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @templatetyedef awesome answer! thank you so clear!! I dont know why the textbook couldn't be a bit more explicit for beginners! thanks again!